# how i can use a specific ip of vps for sending curl request in php

Tags: php, vps

how i can use a specific ip of vps for sending curl request in php
im trying to use

```
curl_setopt($curlh, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```

but it always select primary ip
i have two ip,s on vps
e.g. primary ip `1.23.45.6`
and secondry ip `1.23.45.7`

it always select primary ip

Comment: Who downvoted this, and why?

Comment: @Pekka웃, Except that... he's doing it correctly.  Obviously, he did Google.

Comment: @user2339574, Do you have any more code to add?  You seem to be making the correct call.

Comment: @Brad yeah, fair point. I didn't catch the param used, sorry OP